# Parse html using Perl

Tags: html, perl, href, read-write

I have the following html-

```
<a href="http://address.com">John</a>: I really <b>love</b> <b>soccer</b>;
```

I want to parse it into a csv where I would have

name = John

comment = I really love soccer.

key words = love, soccer

in the console app, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions.</troll>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example how to do parsing with [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder):

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(<<END_HTML);
<a href="http://address.com">John</a>: I really <b>love</b> <b>soccer</b>;
END_HTML

my $name     = $html->find('a')->as_text;               # "John"
my @keywords = map { $_->as_text } $html->find('b');    # "love", "soccer"
my $comment  = $html->as_text;                          # "John: I really love soccer; "
```

Cleaning up `$comment` is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 11):

There are plenty of HTML parsers on CPAN, my preferred one is [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath)

[Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) will help you generate a CSV from the extracted data.

Comment: It does help to read the manual, I now have a better understanding